# Approximating an integral with elementary functions

Tags: calculus, asymptotics, improper-integrals

Consider the integral
$$\int_1^\infty\frac{\exp(-nx)}{x}dx$$

We get:$$\int_1^\infty\frac{\exp(-nx)}{x}dx=n\int_ n^\infty\frac{\exp(-x)}{x}=nE_1(n)$$

My question is, can we approximate this integral with elementary functions for large n?

I've found out that $$\frac {e^{-n}} n> \int_1^\infty\frac{\exp(-nx)}{x}dx$$
As,$$\int_1^\infty\frac{\exp(-nx)}{x}dx<\int_1^\infty{\exp(-nx)}dx$$
Also,$$\int_1^\infty\frac{\exp(-nx)}{x}dx>\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{\exp(-nk)(1-\exp(-n))}{n(k+1)}=\frac{\exp(-n)}{2n}+\mathcal{O}(1)\exp(-2n)$$

Comment: Asymptotics for the exponential integral are discussed at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral#Asymptotic_.28divergent.29_series --- does that help?

Comment: Recall that this integration is not convergence!

Comment: @GerryMyerson It does.Thanks.

Comment: A [related problem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/396297/evaluating-lim-n-rightarrow-infty-2n1-int-0-1-xn-ex-dx/396322#396322).

Answer (score 3):

Integration by parts does the trick here:

$$\begin{align}n \int_n^{\infty} dx \frac{e^{-x}}{x} &=e^{-n} - n \int_n^{\infty} dx \frac{e^{-x}}{x^2}\\&= e^{-n} -\frac{e^{-n}}{n} + 2 n \int_n^{\infty} dx \frac{e^{-x}}{x^3} \end{align}$$

and so on.  The full asymptotic expansion is

$$n \int_n^{\infty} dx \frac{e^{-x}}{x} \sim e^{-n} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k \, k!}{n^k} \quad (n \to \infty)$$

Note that the sum is a divergent series for a fixed, finite $n$, which means practically, you evaluate the sum for a given $n$ such that the last term used is a minimum in magnitude.

Comment: @Ishan, you can check when the terms in the series begin to increase in magnitude by solving $k!/n^k = (k+1)!/n^{k+1}$, giving $k = n-1$.  So a good approximation is $$n \int_n^{\infty} dx \frac{e^{-x}}{x} \approx e^{-n} \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{(-1)^k \, k!}{n^k}.$$